# awk group by and print if matches a condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have this structure:

```
aaa,up
bbb,down
aaa,down
aaa,down
aaa,up
bbb,down
ccc,down
ccc,down
ddd,up
ddd,down
```

And I would like to have the next output:

```
aaa,up
bbb,down
ccc,down
ddd,up
```

So, the firs thing is to group by. Then, if at least one line is up print up else print down.

So far I have this:

```
awk -F"," '$2=="up"{arr[$1]++}END{for (a in arr) print a,arr[a]}'
```

Then I change $2=="down" and join the two results into one. But with this, I have duplicated values for up's and down's.

Sometimes, instead of ups and downs I receive 0,1,2,3,4 which are more variables and the up status is 0 and 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the end result just to take only the first "aaa" line, the first "bbb" line, etc.? That's what it looks like, and if so, you're over-complicating it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about save the value you see, with a preference for "up"?

```
awk -F "," '$2 ~ /0^(0|1)$/ { $2 = "up" }
    $2 ~ /^[2-9]/ { $2 = "down" }
    $2 == "up" || !($1 in a) { a[$1]=$2 }
    END { OFS=FS; for(k in a) print k, a[k] }' file | sort
```

That is, if the value is "up", we always save it.  Otherwise, we only save the value if we don't yet have a value for this key.

I'm not sure I grasped your 0,1,2,3,4 requirement.  The first lines now convert a number into either "up" or "down".

Comment: Thanks! and fot 0,1,2,3,4 what I meant was that o and 1 mean "up" and 2,3,4 mean "down".

But with this, i'm not printing the value "down" for the lines that didt'n match an "up" status.

Comment: Should not be hard to figure out. But updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) one, but imho it's sufficiently different to have an answer on its own, in particular I think that the logical flow is clearer by skipping processing when the variable has already been "upped", and the job of discriminating the different possible types of $2 is handled to a simple user function

```
awk -F"," '
function up_p(x){
    if(x==0||x=="down") return "down"; else return "up"
    }
a[$1]=="up" {next}
            {a[$1]=up_p($2)}
END         {for(k in a) print k "," a[k]}' file | sort
aaa,up
bbb,down
ccc,down
ddd,up
```

---

On second thought, the user function is unnecessary...

```
awk -F"," '
a[$1]=="up" {next}
            {a[$1]=($2==0||$2=="down")?"down":"up"}
END         {for(k in a) print k "," a[k]}' file | sort
aaa,up
bbb,down
ccc,down
ddd,up
```

but it comes down to personal taste so I leave both versions in my answer.